# SonarQube readonly permissions

Tags: sonarqube

I don't find a way to allow authenticated user to only view the information in SonarQube but change nothing. Is it possible, at all?

The minimal role is "BROWSE: Access a project, browse its measures, and create/edit issues for it." which is too much unprotective.

I am using the latest version: 5.6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, there is currently no way to prevent an authenticated user to comment an issue for instance. The same way on Github there is no way to prevent an authenticated user to comment any issue.

Comment: here it is not just comment but also change status, isn't it?

Comment: No, to be able to "resolve" and issue, change its severity or type, this requires to have the "Administer Issues" permission but indeed this is not obvious based on the permission descriptions. Thanks for the feedback, we're going to improve the descriptions in the next upcoming version of SonarQube.